# Word count in a Notes Text Field

Tags: word-count

I want to limit the number of words a person can enter in a text field.  How can I track the number of words (by using a second field) in that field as each word is entered?

Comment: And on what platform?  (HTML, Winforms, VB.NET) ?

Answer (score 2):

use this js (using jquery):

```
$('#newKeywords').bind('change', function() {

   $('#wordsLong').text($('#newKeywords').val().split(' ').length + 1);

});
```

and this html:

```
<textarea id="newKeywords"></textarea>
<div>The text consists of <span id="wordsLong"></span> keywords.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Media College](http://www.mediacollege.com) :

[Limit the Number of Characters in a Textarea or Text Field in javaScript](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/limit-characters.html)